# WebDriver remove element from page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver(ChromeDriver). I need to remove some elements from page after processing(from DOM model).

For example I have a following element:

```
WebElement starRatingElement = reviewElement.findElement(By.className("review-info-star"));
```

How to remove `starRatingElement` from browser DOM model ?

How it can be achieved in Java with Selenium WebDriver ? Please show an example.

Comment: Just curious... why do you want to remove elements from the DOM?

Comment: I'm parsing AJAX enabled site and noticed elements overflow during continuous incremental data loading

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'll have to execute a JavaScript code to make any DOM changes.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
}
js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('review-info-star')[0].remove();");
```

Comment: Just a note of clarification... this doesn't actually remove the element from the DOM, it just hides it (makes it not visible).

Comment: Thanks @JeffC and alexanoid for the correction. I've made the changes to the answer.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which does not have a `remove()` method -- could use `document.getElementsByClassName('review-info-star')[0].remove()`

Comment: You can use: `document.querySelectorAll('.review-info-star').forEach(function(element) {element.remove();});`

Comment: How do you send a variable with the name of the element you want to delete to the Javascript?