# Delete Element on a page Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to delete this element so it is not showed anymore on my page, using node.js, how could i do this using xpath or css selector?

```
<div class="antigate_solver recaptcha solved"><a class="status" tabindex="0" title="AntiCaptcha: Captcha solving status"></a><a class="control" title=""></a></div><div class="antigate_solver recaptcha solved"><a class="status" tabindex="0" title="AntiCaptcha: Captcha solving status"></a><a class="control" title=""></a></div>
```

Comment: Which element ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOM remove element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830839/javascript-dom-remove-element)

Answer (score -2):

Based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199740/webdriver-remove-element-from-page), you may call the JavascriptExecutor and use the `.remove()` method on the object that you want to get rid of. Note this way of doing it requires an id on the element; however it can be generalized to remove elements of a certain class as well by changing `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName`.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
}
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('element-to-remove').remove();");
```