# How to prevent a particular <script> tag from executing during automated Selenium testing in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy

I have a particular website that has two scripts like so:

```
<html>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Populates input field A with value = B
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Overwrites input field A with value = C
    </script>    
</html>
```

I'm using Selenium WebDriver in Java to test the functionality above. Is there a way that Selenium will allow me to stop the second script from running so that I can test that input field A has value B first before C overwrites it?

I know that when

```java
driver.get("someUrl");
```

is called, the WebDriver will load the entire page. Is there a way that I can stop page load as soon as "B" is populated into field A?

I have tried to use BrowserMob Proxy to replace the second script with a blank one but I'm not sure how to use the filters to do so.

Comment: @bengalsfan123 How would you do that manually?

Comment: @DebanjanB I can do that manually via using a Charles proxy in my browser. I can intercept the HTTP response, modify the second script to be blank, and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is application base.
Selenium do not control your application business logic. it just mimic the action you will do manually.

There is one class called javascript executor in selenium.
You can delete the html section using it, it will work if your if the event or your javascript of html call after doing any operation i.e. click. you can use `driver.navigate().refresh();` when you again want your original DOM

code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
}
js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('review-info-star')[0].remove();");
```

Source:

[WebDriver remove element from page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199740/webdriver-remove-element-from-page)

Note: It's just an approach, it again depend on your application.